# Update a column with records from current row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing SQL Server table `Employees` with 3 columns `month`, `year` and `day` as date parts.

Now I have added a new column `createdate` where I want to insert date as a combination of all 3 columns from the current row.

[image]

Comment: You can also use Datefromparts to form a date.

Comment: year, but if i have some invalid date-part then it will not handle that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE Employees 
SET createdate = TRY_PARSE(CAST([year] AS VARCHAR(4)) + '/' + CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST([day] AS VARCHAR(2)) AS DATETIME)
```

If you have invalid data in Month Or Year Or Day Colunm, then above query will update with NULL Value.

NOTE: Try_Parse will work from Sql Server Version 2012 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

You can as the below:

```
UPDATE Employees 
SET createdate = CAST(CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)) + '.' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)) + '.' + CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEFROMPARTS` very simple to form date

```
UPDATE Employees SET CreateDate =DATEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's update for all rows :

```
UPDATE Employees SET CreateDate = [day] +'/'+ [Month] +'/'+ [year]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   1)...UPDATE Employees 
    set createdate =
           CAST(
              CAST(year AS VARCHAR(4)) +
              RIGHT('0' + CAST(month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
              RIGHT('0' + CAST(day AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
           AS DATETIME)


    2)...SELECT
        DATEADD(year, [year]-1900, DATEADD(month, [month]-1, DATEADD(day, [day]-1, 0)))
    FROM
        dbo.Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UPDATE emp SET CreateDate =( SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))+'-'+
                CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2))))
```

[image: img1]

or
you can also use this code:

```
 UPDATE empl SET CreateDate =( SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),
                CAST([Month] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                CAST([Day] AS VARCHAR(2))+'-'+CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4)),101))
```

[image: img2]